# Sort a table in a canvas game?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So a friend and I programmed a dart game with javascript and made a table to submit highscores. The submitting works more or less fine, the only problem is, that we have no idea how to sort the table by the amount of points.

Here's the code for the submitting:

```
function submitScore() {
  var table = document.getElementById("scoreTable");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
  cell2.innerHTML = points;
  cell3.innerHTML = nameofLevel;

  document.getElementById("scoresTitle").style.visibility="visible";
  document.getElementById("submitButton").style.visibility="hidden";
  document.getElementById("nameText").style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to sort the always updated table by points?

Comment: does this HAVE to be data in the DOM? Using the DOM to store state data is a very bad idea. The DOM has sever performance issues. Better to have a in memory representation of the data in JavaScript, do your changes on that and then render a new table that overwrites the one in the DOM to reflect the change.

Comment: Just a reminder that, as part of etiquette, you should choose a right answer eventually :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to sort the data in memory and create a new table to reflect that change.

First, there seems to be a lot of state involved with scores. This offers an opportunity to make a finite state machine to manage the score data:

```
function Player(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.score = 0;
}
Player.prototype.addScore = function(turnScore) {
  this.score += turnScore;
};

function ScoreBoard(tallys) {
  // Allow a default of an empty array.
  // Also allow a predefined array. Used for immutability later on.
  this.scoreTallys_ = tallys || [];
}
ScoreBoard.prototype.addTurn = function(player, turnScore, nameOfLevel) {
  this.scoreTallys_.push({
    player:      player,
    points:      turnScore,
    nameOfLevel: nameOfLevel
  });
  player.addScore(turnScore);
};
```

With a `Player` and a `ScoreBoard` object we can expand their roles as needed. For example the ScoreBoard can be responsible to create an HTML table representation of the scores:

```
ScoreBoard.prototype.buildTBody = function() {
  var rowsHtml = this.scoreTallys_.map(function(tally) {
    return '<tr><td>' + tally.player.name +
      '</td><td>' + tally.points +
      '</td><td>' + tally.nameOfLevel +
      '</td></tr>';
  }).join('');
  return '<tbody>' + rowsHtml + '</tbody>';
};
ScoreBoard.prototype.render = function() {
  var table = document.getElementById('score-board');
  table.innerHTML = this.buildTBody();
};
```

Let us add a sorting method to this:

```
ScoreBoard.prototype.sort = function() {
  function sorter(a,b) {
    return b.points - a.points;
  }
  // This creates a new array (clone) but the objects are not copied only the
  // references to them. Then we sort them according the the above sorter function.
  var scores = this.scoreTallys_
    .slice(0)
    .sort(sorter);
  // Return a new ScoreBoard. Immutability is an advantage in design like this.
  return new ScoreBoard(scores);
};
```

Now we can create and render a table either normal or sorted:

```
myScoreBoard.render();        // Render in order of points as they were added.
myScoreBoard.sort().render(); // Render in order of points.
```

For reference: [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zevuru/2/edit) is a possible version of this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In your current implementation, it is difficult to sort the table by points because the data is stored nowhere except the table itself. Because of this, one cannot simply erase the table and then generate new HTML for the child rows. In the future, it is advisable to store the points in an array of objects. This 'separation of data from presentation' has many advantages. Further documentation for doing so is available easily on the internet.

Try calling the following code right AFTER you finish updating your table.

```
function sortByPoints(){
    var theTable = document.getElementById("scoreTable")
    var tableHead = table.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0] || theTable;
    var rows = theTable.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    //rows is not an Array, but an HTMLCollection. Convert HTMLCollection into Array in the following line.
    rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(rows);

    var sortedRows = rows.sort(function(a,b){
        var pointsInA = a.getElementsByTagName('td')[1];
        var pointsInB = b.getElementsByTagName('td')[1];

        //sort in descending order
        if (pointsInA > pointsInB) return -1;
        if (pointsInA < pointsInB) return 1;
        return 0;
    });

    sortedRows.forEach(function(a){
        tableHead.appendChild(a);
    }
}
```